# ANDROID apps installed on my phone without my permission- i think my flatmate is controlling my phone?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, settings, bluetooth, permissions

Can someone you live with install android permissions to your apps on your phone and control your phone. Strange things are happening on my phone and I can't change permissions on apps and other apps are installed and and I never installed them and I can't uninstall them.
It's making me paranoid and I just want proof who installed them- can anyone help?
I have a Samsung s21 ultra and a Google account which sometimes I get logged out of and password changed. I did factory settings but the same thing happened again. I'm really stressed. Wifi and Bluetooth get turned on and data is being used. Once wifi calling was on when I switched my phone on and sim 2 was in use- I don't have a sim 2! Help me please.

Comment: there will be no proof who installed them. is Samsung Knox Secure Folder still working - then your phone is secure. just remove all google accounts and samsung accounts from phone, factory reset phone from settings and never use the same accounts again

Comment: If someone has access to your Google account installing apps via Play Store web site to your device is simple. Consider activating two factor authentication for your Google account. But make yourself familiar with the consequences of two factor auth and keep the backup codes in a safe place.

Comment: okay there *is* one way to proof.. write some whatsapp to any of your (dedicated) contacts your flatmate is your swarm or other stupid things which will confuse your flatmate.. things only the suspect can know.. socialscam the hacker :D